# graph.facebook.com/me/home photos width and height

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get width and height for photos from `/me/home`?

I try

```
/me/home?fields=picture,width,height
```

But no result for width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Graph API do not return the size of the image in terms of width and height.
However, you can specify the size you want to retrieve using 'height' and 'width' parameters e.g:

```
me/picture?width=70&height=90
```

Also, there are some default sizes you can retrieve using 'type' parameter:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/#sizes

In the end, you can retrieve a picture of any size and programmatically get its width and height.

Javascript examples:

Modern browsers and IE9+:

```js
var width = document.getElementById('yourImg').naturalWidth,
    height = document.getElementById('yourImg').naturalHeight;
console.log(width, height);
```

For IE8-:

```js
var img = new Image(), // or document.createElement('img')
    width,
    height;

img.onload = function() {
  width = this.width;
  height = this.height;
};

img.src = 'http://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/626_someid_202729_q.jpg'
console.log(width, height);
```

Comment: The thing is in knowing width and height _before_ the page is served. I need to define width and height attributes for <img> tags to avoid page convulsions.

Comment: What's the difference between setting width and height attributes for <img> before the request and right after it?

Comment: When you set height attribute, the whole page has the same fixed height before and after images are loaded. Otherwise <img> elements have zero height and width until browser knows the dimensions. This leads to jumps of content on slow internet connections.